# Ênclise em "eis"

Tags: sintaxe

Em Português, só temos uso regular de ênclise, próclises e mesóclise em verbos, de maneira articulada com a flexão verbal e com a sua colocação relativa a outros elementos da frase, como preposições, advérbios etc.

Se a palavra *eis* não é verbo, qual a lógica (vigente ou pretérita) para a expressão *Ei-lo*?

Comment: Adicionalmente, *eis* é pronome demonstrativo? É advérbio?

Comment: Também existe *no-lo* (*nos* + *o*) e *vo-lo*: "Não sabem a história?" "Não, ninguém no-la contou."

Comment: Há quem defenda que _eis_ é na verdade um verbo.

Comment: @Jacinto, então se há precedente de ênclise com pronome pessoal oblíquo, já haveria possibilidade para pronome demostrativo.  Contudo, _eis_ não me parece estar na mesma categoria que _esse_, _este_ e _aquele_...  Ele tem um quê de partícula expletiva também...

Comment: Havia mais liberdade com respeito aos pronomes no passado, coisa que vemos fossilizado nas modernas como *ei-lo* no português (e a versão castelhana *helo* — *eis* e *he* funcionam e soam como cognados mais não são, *he* vem do árabe *há* e *eis* do latim *ecce*) o no asturianu com a interrogativa *¿úlo?* (em português, *onde fica ele?*). Agora só temos alguns restos da língua antiga e estas expressões as vezes não têm sentido segundo a gramática moderna.

Comment: @jacinto no caso que dizes, os pronomes *nos* e *vos* não admitem pronome átono como é o caso de *eis*, ambas pertenecen ao mesmo verbo que admite dois complementos —um direto e outro indireto. Imagino que eis poderia admitir dois pronomes também, não é? *Eis-vo-lo aqui* o *eis-tas*, mas provavelmente seria muito pouco usado.

Comment: @guifa Acho _eis_ só aceita pronomes com caso acusativo (_eis_ é um verbo transitivo?). _Eis-lhe_ não é possível.

Comment: Na linguística moderna, há os chamados "pro-verbos", que são termos que comportam-se como verbos e podem substituir sintagmas verbais (da mesma forma que os pronomes podem substituir sintagmas nominais). A palavra "eis" poderia ser, neste ponto de vista moderno, classificada como um pro-verbo (ou talvez como uma pro-frase). Veja [este artigo da Wikipedia anglófona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A palavra eis é um advérbio. Provavelmente provenha de heis (haver/haveis), o que justificaria a adição dos pronomes pessoais. É usada pela 1.ª pessoa do discurso para indicar ao ouvinte o que está perto ou presente, o que está próximo no tempo, o que vai dizer: Jesus disse a sua mãe: -- Mulher, eis o teu filho. / Eis, eleitores, a hora oportuna. / Eis o que os senhores devem fazer. Unem-se-lhe com hífen os pronomes pessoais átonos me, te, o, a, nos, vos: eis-me, eis-te, ei-lo, ei-la, eis-nos, eis-vos, ei-los, ei-las. Assim, pode-se dizer "Eis o papa" da mesma forma que se diria "Habemus papam", sendo portanto o "Eis" tomado por "haveis", podendo assim levar o "-lo" por esta escusa. Nota-se que no castelhano, língua irmã do português, existiram formas divergentes para a 1ª e 2ª pessoa do plural do verbo haver: hemos/habemos, heis/habéis.

Comment:  Muito boa a sua resposta! Obrigado.